# Ionic go to new view with same state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am creating a view of files in my ionic app.
It is exactly like the explorer in your computer, it displays directories and files and you can click on directories to view other directories and files inside itself.

To achieve this, I have my state 'menu.files' (cause I have a menu with navigation)
which takes a path in parameter.
So, that is a part of my code:

In the view:

```js
<div ng-repeat="file in files" style="..." ng-click="openPath(file)">
```

In the Controller:

```html
$scope.openPath = function(path) {
    console.log(path);
    $state.transitionTo("menu.files", {
        path: $scope.path + "/" + newPath
    });
}
```

The problem:

The view is reloading itself but it stays on the same view...

I mean, in top-left there is no back-arrow, previous view is just like 'replaced'.
I want to have the same behavior of when I make a $stage.go() to another view, they stack in navigation and user can go back.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: why not just use states? with state id's and nested states?

Comment: Because I can have an infinite number of states i.e. on state per directory